# Using a Controller Method with Resque Background Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, redis, resque

I am on Rails 4 using Resque with Redis.

How can I use a controller method, which is currently defined in my application_controller, inside of my background job?

Here is the current method I have defined:

```
def push_to_google(token, message)
  if token.present?
    gcm = GCM.new("843jf9384fj839f848j890fj3")
    registration_ids = ["#{token}"] # an array of one or more client registration tokens
    options = {data: {notification: "#{message}"}}
    response = gcm.send(registration_ids, options)
  end
end
```

which I would like to use in this background job defined in my delayed_notifications:

```
class DelayedNotifications
  @queue = :notifications_queue

  def self.perform(registration_id, user_name)
    push_to_google(registration_id, "New message from #{user_name}.")
  end
end
```

Of course, my jobs are currently failing with this error:

`undefined method 'push_to_google' for DelayedNotifications:Class`

Answer (score 1):

Extract (move) `push_to_google` to `ApplicationHelper` and include `ApplicationHelper` in your `ApplicationController` as well as `DelayedNotifications`.

After changes, your `application_helper.rb` should be:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # other methods

  def push_to_google(token, message)
    if token.present?
      gcm = GCM.new("843jf9384fj839f848j890fj3")
      registration_ids = ["#{token}"] # an array of one or more client registration tokens
      options = {data: {notification: "#{message}"}}
      response = gcm.send(registration_ids, options)
    end
  end
end
```

`application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper

end
```

`delayed_notifications.rb`:

```
class DelayedNotifications
  include ApplicationHelper

  @queue = :notifications_queue

  def self.perform(registration_id, user_name)
    push_to_google(registration_id, "New message from #{user_name}.")
  end
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't put this into `ApplicationHelper` but a dedicated module somewhere in `lib/` instead.  Your approach seems quite dangerous to me as it adds all methods defined in `ApplicationHelper` as controller actions. For this reason I'd include the method as private.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think I will take that approach. Are there any benefits as to putting my module into the `lib` directory vs the `helpers` directory? @BoraMa

Comment: @Kathan There is a slight difference. [Rails helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) (i.e. modules in the `app/helpers` directory) are designed for [moving complex logic out of the views](http://mixandgo.com/blog/the-beginner-s-guide-to-rails-helpers), i.e. they generally deal with the presentation of data. Also, by default all helpers are included in the view namespace (they are usable automatically from views). The `lib` directory is used for any support modules in general. As your code does not seem to deal with presentation, I'd put it into `lib`.

Comment: Even though including `app/helpers` will make those module methods as public methods on the `controller`, which means, those methods can be `actions`, they are not going to be exposed unless you define a route. And even if you define a route, they are not going to work unless you define a corresponding view. So, I wouldn't be paranoid of this approach being dangerous.

Comment: But as @BoraMa mentioned, usually, `app/helpers` is where the complex view logic goes. And you would keep the app specific logic under `lib` directory. At the same time nothing is stopping you from the approach in my answer. If it is a method or two, I tend to keep it in the `app/helpers`, but if the list start growing/ getting complex, I move them to `lib` folder. The reason is that `app/helpers` is already under `authload_paths`, but `lib`, depending on the `rails` version, you need to add it to the `autoload_paths`.

Comment: @Dharam, you are right about the actions not being exposed unless a route was created for them (or unless you'd have e.g. a `destroy` method in the helper that would be matched by a `resource` route). I'm sorry for the confusion. OTOH your claim about "the action still not working without a view" seems irrelevant - the code in the action would very well run before failing due to missing view and my concerns were exactly about exposing a callable code outside its intended context.

Comment: Anyway, I simply wanted to suggest the principle that code should be placed where it is expected. While it is technically possible, I still tend to think that your answer suggests rather [low-cohesive coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) (various unrelated "utility" helpers placed into `ApplicationHelper` just because it's easy), an approach that IMO leads to a difficult-to-read and understand code in the long term.